# How do i add parameters to a packet and retrieve them?

Tags: omnet++, inet

So i have been successful in my previous packet issues. However i now want to add parameters to my packet and retrieve them. Right now, my code is

```
Packet *pk = new Packet(msgName);
const auto& payload = makeShared<ApplicationPacket>();
payload -> setChunkLength(B(msgByteLength));
pk -> insertAtBack(payload);
pk->addPar("testpara") = "a";
```

Retrieving the packet:

```
void Receiver::processPacket(Packet *pk)
{
    char a = pk->par("testpara");
    EV_INFO << a << endl;
}
```

Im getting the error

> Has no parameter called 'testpara'

Is there a proper way to this?

Comment: Post relevant code if you want answers. We do not know what  your par("blah") and addPar("blah") do without seeing the code. Perhaps the error is same as with char a = "a"; ?

Comment: The code is pretty relevant. They are merely test parameters. The error clearly shows that there is no such parameter called "testpara". Hence i am asking the question on how do i read packets or retrieve paramters from packets.

Comment: Should it be possible to retrieve a char from parameter when you clearly assigned string literal to it?

Comment: That doesn't really matter here as its for testing purposes. The main issue is that it can't find a parameter named "testpara". Either im adding it wrongly or retrieving it wrongly.

Comment: May be you are passing it around wrongly, sending it wrongly or receiving it wrongly how should we know? Your "pretty relevant" code does contain nothing of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is not correct. Adding a parameter to a packet will add only a parameter object, but that parameter and all tags and other metainfo will be stripped from the packet once it is placed on the network. Only data that is actually inside the packet definition (i.e. what is serialized and placed on the physical medium) will be transmitted.

The proper way is, to add your data inside the ApplicationPacket.msg definition and then you will be able to set those directly on the `payload`. (the message compiler will generate the necessary setter/getter methods).

BTW the [ApplicationPacket](https://github.com/inet-framework/inet/blob/master/src/inet/applications/base/ApplicationPacket.msg) you are using is just an example in INET which contains a `sequenceNumber` as data. But you can define your own structure of the payload, just extend the `FieldsChunk` class in the `.msg` file and use that as the payload in your application code.

TLDR: Parameters should never be used in INET on packets. Tags should be used only for cross-layer communication inside the same host. Data meant to be transmitted should always be defined inside the `.msg` files.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Yeah i figured that out a few days back. I sent data through the data segment of the packet. I thought it was somewhat of a workaround but it turns out that it's the correct thing to do. Thanks!